# Symfony 2: How to pass an object of a custom class to controller through AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, object

Ι have an entity class, named Product that looks like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
protected $name;
}
```

In an action of a controller, I retrieve all the products from my database in order to print some of their attributes in a twig template:

```
$products = $repository->findAll();
return $this->render('abcNikBundle:Prod:products.html.twig', array('products' => $products));
```

My problem is that I want to pass this array of objects (of class Product) back to another action and do some stuff, through an AJAX call when a button is clicked. I tried to use json_encode() in my twig template and then json_decode() in my php action but it didn't worked. In my twig template I use json_encode like this:

```
var products = {{ products|json_encode() }};
```

My AJAX function looks like this:

```
$.post(Routing.generate('ajaxRoute', { prods: products  }), function( data ) {
    $('#ajax_result').html(data);
});
```

Finally in my controller:

```
public function ajaxAction(Request $request) {
    $myArray = $request->get('prods');
    $myArray2 = json_decode($myArray);
    return new Response(var_dump($myArray2));
}
```

Is there any clear way to pass an object (of a custom class) or an array of objects through an AJAX call? How can this be done?

Comment: IDK if it helps, but try `var products = "{{ products|json_encode() }}";` Because you need unserialized data to be passed to `$.post`

Comment: If you are not changing the product details in the javascript then what is the benefit of passing the whole product string through the action call? It would make for a much smaller request if you just passed the id's and then find them again on the AJAX action?

Comment: Qoop: Your solution was already one of my alternatives but it would be a lot easier for me if I could get the whole array at once.
Ziumin: Probably you're right. I tried your suggestion too but anyway that wasn't my real problem at first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle). You can set up all the fields that are need to be converted. Then you can just serialize your objects to pass to JS:

```
var products = {{ products|serialize('json') }};
```

And deserialize in your controller:

```
public function ajaxAction(Request $request) {
    $serializer = $container->get('jms_serializer');
    $myArray = $request->get('prods');
    $myArray2 = $serializer->deserialize($myArray, 'Acme\YourBundle\Entity\Product', 'json');
    return new Response(var_dump($myArray2));
}
```

Comment: I would use [Symfony's JsonResponse](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#creating-a-json-response)

Comment: I took `return` statement from the question. I think that author knows better what he want;-)

Comment: Agreed, just adding the note in case the author wanted to try using that :)

Comment: As you can see from the question author makes a standard ajax request that expects to retrieve plain text/html. And then place all retrieved data into html-element without any modifications. Encoding and decoding JSON in this case is useless overhead.

Comment: I tried to serialize both an array of objects and a single using JMSSerializeBundle, but turns out that my array(or object) is too big to be serialized as I get a fatal error: "Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes)". I guess that I have to choose a different way to implement my functionality, unless you got a solution for this! Thank you anyway, it was a useful help!

Comment: JMSSerializer is very optimized library and so I think that you can't find any better solution. I think that you need to allocate more memory by setting `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`. Or if you really have smaller objects it can be caused by misconfiguration of your serialization rules. Maybe you have many collections inside every your object? You should exclude it form serialization.